# Running number of items in subgroups within ienumerable of items

Tags: c#, .net, linq, f#, functional-programming

Say I have an

```
IEnumerable< IEnumerable< string > > rowsOfTextColumns
```

The inner ienumerable string values represent columns in a row, thus the outer ienumerable stores several rows of text columns.
Like: 3 rows by 4 columns:

```
12345    foo    2014-10-16 09:55    blah
12345    foo    2014-10-16 09:55    bleh
67890    bar    2014-10-16 09:58    ugh
```

The DateTime column values are not unique - as you can see in the example, several entries at the same time are possible. But datetime makes most sense to use as ID in my data.
Since I want a unique ID for each row, I would like to add a column to each row "on the fly", which contains the number of occurence from entries with same datetime, starting with 1. Like this:

```
12345     foo     2014-10-16 09:55    blah    (1)
12345     foo     2014-10-16 09:55    bleh    (2)
67890     bar     2014-10-16 10:21    ugh     (1)
```

(For clarification: the unique id would be a compound of datetime + running number within datetime subgroup)

Sure I know how to do this *some* way.
But - how is this done most elegantly, e.g. using LINQ / functional programming aspects of C#?
Furthermore I am curious, how would the same be done most elegantly in F#?

**EDIT #1:** better illustrated the source data format

**EDIT #2:**
Allright, using groupby as suggested in one comment, I got this so far (in C#, look at my selected Answer for F# code):

```
var groupsByDatetime = rowsOfColumns.GroupBy( rec => rec.ElementAt(2) );
var extendedRows =
    groupsByDatetime.SelectMany( g =>
        g.Select( (columns,i) =>
            columns.Concat( new[]{(1+i).ToString()} ) ) );
```

Anyone bids *less*? :)
Well doesn't look too bad already I guess.

Comment: are you trying to split the lines then process from there.. i'm not sure what you are trying to do here.. perhaps you can show some existing code that you have or have tried ..to make things a little more clearer

Comment: How about highlighting shortcomings in my question instead just downvoting...

Comment: Did you consider a groupby() on the date?

Comment: How is my explanation not clear?
What do you mean "split the lines"? Which lines?

My goal is to become more proficient in the more modern aspects of the language instead doing everything the "old way" - if and when it makes sense.
So I thought I'll post a specific example that just happened to come up.

Comment: honestly that does not look like IEnumberable<string> this is why I have asked to show a coded example for example I would expect to see something like this 
`IEnumerable<string> someEnum = new IEnumerable<string>() { "2", "4", "6"};` maybe I am not fully understanding  your question

Comment: groupby - this looks like something that goes in the right direction, I'll ponder that. Sounds database-y, but I'm not a DB programmer so it's not in my "active vocabular" :)

Comment: DJ: I said Enumerable OF Enumerable OF string. Parted in columns and rows. Maybe I'll put that part in a code block and write it like C# so it's better visible...

Comment: updated original post

Comment: is this c# or f# it can't be two languages.

Comment: Hogan, I ownly know C# which my given code is in, but asked for an F# solution because I am interested. You often hear how many things are yet more elegant in F# even though C# was extended with all those "sorta functional programming" goodies. I'd find it interesting to see such comparisons with some real life little problems right out of my mind :)

Comment: Addenum: of course just one example won't give me a good impresison of this, I might have chosen a particularly meaningless exmample for this.
So I'll probably do this a few more times when I'm thinking of this, hopefully not annoying any folks here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This groups the items and maps each item to include its index within the group.

```
let groupAndIndexItems keySelector =
    Seq.groupBy keySelector
    >> Seq.map (fun (key, items) -> 
        let indexedItems = items |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> x, i)
        key, indexedItems
    )
```

Example usage:

```
[
    12345, "foo", "2014-10-16 09:55", "blah"
    12345, "foo", "2014-10-16 09:55", "bleh"
    67890, "bar", "2014-10-16 09:58", "ugh"
]
|> groupAndIndexItems (fun (_, _, s, _) -> s)
```

Output:

```
val it : seq<string * seq<(int * string * string * string) * int>> =
  seq
    [("2014-10-16 09:55",
      seq [((12345, "foo", "2014-10-16 09:55", "blah"), 0);
           ((12345, "foo", "2014-10-16 09:55", "bleh"), 1)]);
     ("2014-10-16 09:58", 
      seq [((67890, "bar", "2014-10-16 09:58", "ugh"), 0)])]
```

Comment: Ah, looks pretty similar to my C# version. Just that my mind likes the word "map" a lot more than "select" for what this does :-D

Comment: Do you need to preserve the original order?

Comment: No I don't care for the order in this particular instance - sounds like you have something up your sleeve that doesn't preserve it?